# How can I aggregate over arrays inside documents in MongoDB and get counts for multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, json, xml, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am writing a program that takes in an XML file of vehicle reflash data and converts it to JSON so it can be stored in a MongoDB database. The XML starts like this:

```
<FlashReportGeneratorTag>
    <VehicleEntry>
        <VehicleStatus>PASSED</VehicleStatus>
    </VehicleEntry>
    <VehicleEntry>
        <VehicleStatus>PASSED</VehicleStatus>
    </VehicleEntry>
</FlashReportGeneratorTag>
```

After I convert it to JSON and add the project identifier I am left with a format kinda like this:

```
{
    "FlashReportGeneratorAddedTag" : {
        "VehicleEntry" : [
            {
                "VehicleStatus" : "PASSED"
            }, 
            {
                "VehicleStatus" : "PASSED"
            }
        ]
    },
    "project_id" : "1234"
}
```

What I would like to do is get an aggregate count of number of vehicles passed and number of vehicles failed within each document for project 1234 but I have had no luck.

I have tried using the basic aggregation skills I know but I cannot simply group by project_id since that will group by document, when I need to aggregate over an array inside of it. I also haven't found any resources that tell you if you can or cannot aggregate two values at once (get sum of passed and sum of failed counts).

As a very last resort I could change the document style around to just have each VehicleEntry be its own document, but I would like to take and store the XML as it is if I can.

**EDIT** Using Unwind I was able to setup an aggregation for the array that I'm looking for:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate().Match(new BsonDocument { { "project_id", "1234" } }).Unwind(i => i["FlashReportGeneratorAddedTag.VehicleEntry"]);
```

However, I cannot find the proper way to group these in order to get the pass/fail counts throughout the array. I assume there is some way I need to use the Match function but I can't figure out how to do that without excluding one of the two conditions. Do I have to run aggregation twice, once for passed and once for failed?

Comment: Have you looked at using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I have not but it looks promising, let me play with that idea I think I can make it work.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Unwind did work, but I am still facing trouble aggregating two conditions, please see my edit if you think you have an idea.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Sorry for the third ping but I made this work. I'll share my own answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a hint from JohnnyHK and some more digging I was able to work this out. First I had to use the `Unwind` method to unwind the `Vehicleentry` array in order to aggregate on it:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate().Match(new BsonDocument { { "project_id", "1234" } })
   .Unwind(i => i["FlashReportGeneratorAddedTag.VehicleEntry"])
```

Once I had that I was able to nest `BsonDocuments` in order to sum based on a condition. In order to get the passed count I used this:

```
{ "passed", new BsonDocument { { "$sum", new BsonDocument { { "$cond", new BsonArray { new BsonDocument { { "$eq", new BsonArray { "$FlashReportGeneratorAddedTag.VehicleEntry.VehicleStatus", "PASSED" } } }, 1, 0 } } } } } }
```

Similarly I added in a failed tab. The whole thing (not yet formatted) was like this:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(Vehicles);
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
.Match(new BsonDocument{ { "project_id", "1234" } })
.Unwind(i => i["FlashReportGeneratorAddedTag.VehicleEntry"])
.Group(new BsonDocument
{ 
    { "_id", "$project_id" },
    { "passed", new BsonDocument
        { { "$sum", new BsonDocument
                { { "$cond", new BsonArray
                        { new BsonDocument
                            { { "$eq", new BsonArray 
                                {
                                    "$FlashReportGeneratorAddedTag.VehicleEntry.VehicleStatus", 
                                    "PASSED"
                                } }
                                },
                            1,
                            0 } } } } } 
    },
    { "failed", new BsonDocument
        { { "$sum", new BsonDocument
                { { "$cond", new BsonArray
                        { new BsonDocument
                            { { "$eq", new BsonArray 
                                {
                                    "$FlashReportGeneratorAddedTag.VehicleEntry.VehicleStatus", 
                                    "FAILED"
                                } }
                                },
                            1,
                            0 } } } } } 
    },
});
var results = await aggregate.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK I will try my best but it expands really large. I will try to keep it clean. I would like to ask you another question because I appeared to jump the gun. This works on a single document, but if I have two documents for project "1234" I can't seem to sum each into one final result document.