# Aggregating Lists inside of a List of objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398502/how-can-i-aggregate-over-arrays-inside-documents-in-mongodb-and-get-counts-for-m), where I needed to aggregate over inner arrays in MongoDB, I am trying to accomplish the same task in LINQ.

I am close, as I have figured out how to aggregate over an individual item:

```
// Get collection
var collection = _database.GetCollection<VehicleDataUpload>("Vehicles");

// Get first project that meets our identifier
var firstProject = collection.AsQueryable().Where(i => i.ProjectId.Equals("1234")).First();

// Get a list of DailySummaryData objects 
var aggregation = 
    from entry in firstProject.VehicleEntries
    group entry by entry.Data
    into result
    select new DailySummaryData() {
        ProjectName = firstProject.ProjectId,
        Date = result.FirstOrDefault().Date,
        Passed = result.Sum(x => (x.VehicleStatus.Equals("PASSED") ? 1 : 0)),
        Failed = result.Sum(x => (x.VehicleStatus.Equals("FAILED") ? 1 : 0))
    };

return aggregation.ToList();
```

However, I can't use `...First()` on the collection, because there might be multiple VehicleDataUploads for a project. How can I aggregate over all the lists inside the list of documents that are returned?

Comment: What's the problem? You don't want to filter by a single Project Id, but have the same result for all the projects? Correct?

Comment: Close! I need to filter by a project ID, but that could return multiple documents. So when I call `var firstProject = collection.AsQueryable().Where(i => i.ProjectId.Equals("1234")).First();` I would rather be able to say `var uploads = collection.AsQueryable().Where(i => i.ProjectId.Equals("1234")).ToList()` And then do the same aggregation as above but for *each element* in `uploads`. Is that more clear?

Comment: Have you tried just removing `.First()?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something as follows:

```
// Get collection
var collection = _database.GetCollection<VehicleDataUpload>("Vehicles");

// Get first project that meets our identifier
var aggregation = collection
    .AsQueryable()
    // This will return an IEnumerable of Vehicles object
    .Where(i => i.ProjectId.Equals("1234"))
    // Assuming you want to return a plain list, you should use SelectMany
    .SelectMany(v => v.VehicleEntries
        // You group each list of VehicleEntries
        .GroupBy(ve => ve.Data)
        // For each group you return a new DailySummaryData object
        .Select(g => new DailySummaryData() {
            ProjectName = v.ProjectId,
            Date = g.Key,
            Passed = g.Sum(x => (x.VehicleStatus.Equals("PASSED") ? 1 : 0)),
            Failed = g.Sum(x => (x.VehicleStatus.Equals("FAILED") ? 1 : 0))
        })

return aggregation.ToList();
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! The *only* problem is that I can't do `ProjectName = v.ProjectId` I believe becaues v is out of scope now. I tried setting it manually using the input string: `ProjectName = argumentPassedToMethod` but that gives me a MongoCommandException saying the aggregate field doesn't start with $.

Comment: I'm going to accept this anyways, as it did what I want. I just need to find the right way to add the project name into the result items.

Comment: Consider you have the information in any of the object of your group, so you could try something like g.First().ProjectId.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't work because each VehicleEntry doesn't hold the project Id. I will break down the pipeline into steps and try to figure it out, will keep you updated.